# Regular expression to accept both positive and negative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a regular expression that helps me to accept both positive and negative numbers

I have used `^-?\d*(.\d+)?$` expression

```
validateNegativeNumber(e: any) {
   let input = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
        const reg = /^-?\d*(.\d+)?$/;
        if (!reg.test(input)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

Expected result: 5, +5, -5, 0
Unexpected results: 1.5, -1.5, 5++++, ++5, ---5, 5--, 50--6
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed checking for `+` sign. Also there is no need for capturing groups.

Use this:

`^[+-]?\d+$`

1. An optional `+` or `-` sign at the beginning
2. Followed by one or more digits till the end

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g7qyp9/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pattern` attribute of `input` tag in HTML, like below:

```html
<input pattern="^[+-]?\d+$">
```

Explanation: `pattern` attribute is available, it is better use rather than calling a function that validates the input. That will be an extra work.

I hope it helps.

Comment: it will match `+` or `-` also even if there's no digit after it, i think you must be using `\d+` instead of `\d*`

Comment: I will suggest you to add some explanation, why OP's code isn't working and why yours will, that will help them to learn new thing instead of just wondering it is magic, anyways +1

Answer (score 0):

Use this, for accept positive or negative both number.

```
^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

`^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`

Explanation:

`^` matches the beginning of the string (so "abc212" will not validate)

`[+-]?` the first allowed char che be + o - matching 0 or 1 occurrence (the `?`). Note that if you don't want the `+` sign, you can just write `-?`, so the regex will validate matching 0 or 1 occurrence of `-` as first char

`\d+` after that you can have any number of digits (at least one, because we user the `+`)

`(?:\.\d+)?` at the end we can have 0 or 1 occurrence (given by the `?`) of a dot (`\.`) followed by any number of digits (`\d+`). Note that the `?:` at the beginning of the group says that this is a "non-capturing group")

`$` matches the ending of the string (so "231aaa" will not validate)

Answer (score -1):

How about this one?

```js
const reg = /^[+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?$/;

const valids = ['+5', '-5', '5', '-5', '-0.6', '.55', '555.124'];

const invalids = ['--5', '5+', '5-'];


console.log('testing for valids array');

valids.forEach(valid => {
  console.log(reg.test(valid));
});

console.log('testing for invalids array');

invalids.forEach(invalid => {
  console.log(reg.test(invalid));
});
```

Comment: How is this any different from my answer?

Comment: I have provided some tests data to be able to prove that the regex is working?

Comment: Why do you bother commenting? do we have same approach? do you think I just copied your regex?

Comment: We had the same approach before you modified the regex. That is when I commented. As long as you provide several other ways to solve the problem, it is welcome.

Comment: Lol that's what only you think until I realized my solution is not flexible because I did not consider checking for a numbers with decimal.

Comment: Also, your current solution allows double numbers, whereas the OP doesn't want them to match!

Comment: ^But the problem is you overreact on my answer thinking that I copied your regex, without considering some possible situation, such as we had the same thing going on in our mind and we happened to post our solution at the same time?

Comment: I didn't over-react. I simply asked if anything was different between the two answers as I may well have missed to catch the difference in the first place. It was as polite a question as it can get.